# how can I update a nested object state so that is renders the new state after I click it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

YOu can find this code and the data here: git clone https://github.com/Cerezze/ChallengesDestrib2

This program displays a static array of 7 elements. When clicking the button unlock, I want to make it so the taskName appears next to unlock right after the click. But Im not sure why my prevState does not work. You can find the problem at the bottom of getOneRandomTask I think I am setting the user state wrong. But How can I setUser() so that my state updates immediatly after the click? It is a nested object and array so its very confusing I was hoping for some insight. Thanks in advance for all advice.

```
import { challengeBucket } from "./DB/challengeBucket";
import { user } from "./DB/user";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [u, setUser] = useState({});
  const [cb, setChallengeBucket] = useState([]);
  const [dayTasks, setDayTasks] = useState([]);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('user') !== null && localStorage.getItem('challengeBucket') !== null){
      setUser({...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))});
      setChallengeBucket([...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('challengeBucket'))]);
      setDayTasks([...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).challengeOneDays.dayTasks]);
    }
  },[update]);

  const getOneRandomTask = (i) =>{
      let chalBuck = cb;
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
      let user = u;
      let filteredArr = chalBuck.filter((i, index)=>{
        return index === randomNumber;
      });

      user.challengeOneDays.dayTasks[i].taskName = filteredArr[0].taskName;

      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      setUser(prevState => {
        return {...prevState}}); // here is where I am most likely setting state wrong
    
  }

  const setMockStorage = () =>{
    localStorage.setItem('challengeBucket', JSON.stringify(challengeBucket));
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  const deleteMockStorage = () =>{
    localStorage.removeItem('challengeBucket');
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {setMockStorage}>Set Storage</button>
      <button onClick = {deleteMockStorage}>Delete Storage</button>
      {dayTasks.map(i => {
        return (
          <div key={Math.random()}>
            <span>
             Day {i.day}
            </span>
            <button onClick={()=>getOneRandomTask(i.day - 1)} disabled = {i.lockStatus === "locked"?true: false}>
             {i.lockStatus}
            </button>
            <span>
             {i.taskName}
            </span>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: prevState is the current state of that variable, before the update you are currently doing. In your case, you are reseting the state to {} again. You need to set the user in the state.   setUser({...user}) OR   setUser(prevState => {return {...prevState, ...user}})

Comment: I tried both of these before. I understand the basics of it. But it does not re render after the click. I thought I setUser wrong but Now I think that it is a useEffect problem. But I thought that useEffect runs again after state is changed. Why is it not re rendering and showing "task" next to the unlock button? UPDATE: I just realized that I am updating the wrong state here. I should be updating dayTasks, not user, to display the information after click. I think I solved the issue then. Thanks for the input.